# Multi-output neural network combining regression and classification

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, classification, regression

If you have both a classification and regression problem that are related and rely on the same input data, is it possible to successfully architect a neural network that gives both classification and regression outputs?

If so, how might the loss function be constructed?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Usually, for such cases the loss is considered simply a weighted sum of classification loss and regression loss. In other words, your network have 2 independent output parts, one responsible for regression, on which you apply reggression loss L_reg (such as MSE) and another responsible for classification part, on which you apply classification loss L_class (such as cross entropy) and your final optimization criterion is simply (alpha)*L_reg + (1-alpha)*L_class, for some predefined alpha. This allows easy computation of gradients (and overall easy analysis).

Comment: Great, thank you. Is alpha typically treated as a hyper-parameter and tuned as such?

Comment: Yes, unless one can exploit some problem characteristic to find reasonable value

Comment: Can you recommend any R or Python packages for this basic set up?